# How to include classes of main application in to today widgets in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I have got **Class1.h** in the main Application. And I have to use Class1.h in the Today Widget in iOS. What is the method to **share** the classes among the main app and widget in iOS ?

Comment: Put them in a framework.

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode, find Class1.m in the Project Navigator. Select it and, in the File Inspector, check the box next to your Today widget target under Target Membership.

[image]

Then you should be able to import Class1.h in your Today widget code.